# Adding Scrollview pushes entire layout to half view size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a layout like so..

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#333333" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
            <EditText android:autoText="true" android:text="EditText" android:hint="@string/searchBox" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/qbox" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="45dip" android:background="@drawable/search" android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/search"></Button>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="5dip" android:id="@+id/logo" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:paddingLeft="10dip"></ImageView>

            </LinearLayout>
            <com.app.org.HorizontialListView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="150dip" android:id="@+id/hlist" android:background="#FFFFFF"></com.app.org.HorizontialListView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dip" android:paddingLeft="15dip" android:id="@+id/buttonlist" style="@style/tabBar"></LinearLayout>
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/searchresults" android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just added the ScrollView but it appears to push my entire layout into taking up about half the screen size for some reason.. anyone got any Idea why?

Below is an illustration of the affect adding the Scrollview had on the Layout.

```
Layout before ScollView
|---------------------|
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|---------------------|

Layout after ScollView
|---------------------|
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|---------------------|
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to set Full Viewport = true on the scroll view

Comment: nice, that did fix the height issue but sadly my entire linearlayout within the Scrollview isn't scrollable. I can only scroll the listview and not the entire thing. :-( anyidea how I'd fix that?

Comment: You shouldn't put a scrollable item inside a scrollview, that is a best practice, you can adjust your layout accordingly to leave only the listview scrollable and the rest on screen, or you can use the listview method addHeaderView to add an header on the list view that will scroll with it..

Comment: That is `android:fillViewport="true"`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your scrollview tag:

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

Also, you could probably have the ScrollView element be the parent object, instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: ScrollView can only have one child element

Answer (score 2):

set the `android:fillViewport`  attribute to `true` in your `ScrollView`

The `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is not supported/ignored by `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the height of the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.
2. You can't put a ListView inside a ScrollView